# How to convert detected mouth region in gray-scale and binary in android?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am not able to covert the mouth region into grayscale from colour. I have tried everything that I have found through searching on the internet. I am first extracting the mouthare in the detected face and then want to do some image processing on the moutharea, thatswhy i need to convert the moutharea into gray scale.

```
        Mat innerWindow = mRgba.submat(moutharea);
Imgproc.cvtColor(innerWindow, innerWindow,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Comment: Show the image so we can have a better idea what you are trying to do, also show the full code to reproduce the problem, i.e. there is not closing bracket to the loop

Comment: And what is the exact problem, extracting the region, converting it... ?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I want to convert the mouth region into grayscale and then into binary. I am using opencv sample code for FACE DETECTION

Comment: I have updated my code